# Create thread within datagridview loop and retain the row

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to loop through a datagridview and create a new task for each row (to do work on each row simultaneously). If using my current method will it lose the row?

Example: If I had 1000 rows in a datagridview, created a task for each during a loop, then updated parts of the row during the task do I need to somehow pass the row index to the new task instead of below?

For Example:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow locaterow in Form1.form.MainGrid.Rows) //loop through maingrid
                {
                        new Thread(() =>
                        {
                           locaterow.Cells["Mainvalue"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(locaterow.Cells["Mainvalue"].Value) + 1;
                         }).Start();
                 }
```

Will the thread be updating the datagridview row the thread was started on? If not, how can I pass the row index to the new thread to use that after its created?

Comment: don't use a thread for this.

Comment: You can't update UI in non UI thread, you would have to invoke to get back on that thread to do it. Also as @DanielA.White mentioned, `don't use a thread for this`, in all honesty, you don't need to. Why would you want to create a whole new thread to do this?

Comment: The code is just an idea for a stock bot which currently executes orders one by one from a datagridview. This idea was just to improve execution by managing multiple orders at the same time

Comment: The use of `Thread` is now considered the old way and not recommended for most cases since `Task` is introduced. Now you deal with `Task` and the `ThreadPool` only.
And to your problem if you want to do your work in the background move your logic to a task like `Task.Run(()=>{//Do work});` and no need to pass an index becuase you can only update your control from the UI thread so do a `BeginInvoke` each time you want to update a row, it will queue your update to the control.

Comment: do all your computation upfront, then bind it to the ui. you'll have a better rexperience